# mysql: find max of column where entries have multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

Sorry for confusing title. I have a table with a column of hours that each employee has worked. I also have the employee ssn column and the project id column for the project they are working on. I would like to find the project that has been worked on the most, however, I can't use a simple max because each project has multiple rows according to which employee has worked on it for however many hours.

```
EmployeeSSN    ProjectNum    Hours
1              1             20
2              4             30
3              1             15
```

In this example, I would like project 1 to be returned. Below is my code so far

```
select project.pname, works_on.pno, sum(works_on.hours)
from works_on
    join project
        on works_on.pno = project.pnumber
group by works_on.pno
limit 1
```

This is close, it returns the amount of total hours worked on by a particular project (in this case it shows project one because of the limit 1). If there was a way to wrap the sum(works_on.hours) in a max() I think that would do it. However, this gives me an error so I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: your query is not standard sql. Be aware that not grouping by all selected columns mean that the mysql engine will expose remaining data (i.e. `project.pname`) a way that is not meant to be deterministic. Good practice is to standardize sql as much as possible, which in your case means adapting your query to use a subquery selecting and grouping by `works_on.pno` only.

Comment: @Sebas . . . It is fine in this context.  `project.number` is (presumably) an unique or primary key on `project` (technically, this is called *functional dependency*).  Both the MySQL documentation *and* the ANSI standard allow this construct, although it would be better to do the `group by` using `project.number`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if so, then grouping should also involve `project.pname`. I will investigate now your ANSI assertion.

Comment: I cannot find online any other sql version than 1992.

Comment: @paqogomez What do you mean? Example: `CASE` instruction is not standard for sql2, but is standard in sql3. sql3 (1999) is a pretty big deal.

Comment: @Sebas [my mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization)

Comment: Your query just needs an order by. You are limiting 1 row, I see what you're trying to do, but if there's no order, it will pick the first row that appears which is not necessarily the project with the maximum hours.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, page 192 of sql:1992 [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt] you'll find, point 7, the explicit need of selecting columns only if they are included in the group by function.

Comment: @Sebas . . . http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf.  Pay particular attention to the "Group By" subsection in Section 4.18 (entitled "Functional Dependencies") starting on page 50.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks. It makes sense. Just one thing: why do they say `with an additional column CI` as if it could be only one? I can imagine a scenario with more than one column satisfying G -> CI. Is it just a way of putting things, i.e. as in `with any additional columns CI...` ?

Comment: @Sebas . . . The actual reference for `group by` is on page 264 and references feature T301.  This is an optional feature and it can apply to more than one column.  My point is that `group by id` is supported by the ANSI standard (and MySQL and more recent versions of Postgres).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, T301 was the answer. SQL2 doesnt talk about it, SQL3 does. I'm so happy of this founding, I can't believe it is so hard to find. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try to return 1 row with the max hours:

```
select project.pname, works_on.pno, sum(works_on.hours) AS hours
from works_on
    join project
        on works_on.pno = project.pnumber
group by works_on.pno
order by hours desc
limit 1
```

I gave it a quick try on our CRM and it appears to return the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is so close, but you're just missing an order by clause. If you order by the hours worked on a project in decreasing order, and limit 1, you will effectively get the max. Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT p.pname, p.pnumber, SUM(wo.hours) AS totalHours
FROM works_on wo
JOIN project p ON p.pnumber = wo.pno
GROUP BY p.pnumber
ORDER BY totalHours DESC
LIMIT 1;
```